# Can some code run when we first deploy a WAR file?

Tags: tomcat, web-deployment

Is there any method or API  that I can use so that whenever I deploy a new WAR file, a part of code should execute or perhaps when Tomcat starts, the respective servlet should start or run some code continuously.

Answer (score 13):

Reviving an old question since the only answer doesn't show any example.

In order to run a custom piece of code whenever a web application WAR is deployed/undeployed or Tomcat is started/stopped, you need to:

1. Implement the `ServletContextListener` listener and its methods `contextInitialized()` and `contextDestroyed()`.
2. Let Tomcat know about your implementation. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), you can either add the implementing class to the deployment descriptor, annotate it with `WebListener`, or register it via one of the `addListener()` methods defined on `ServletContext`.

Here is an example (based on [this post](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.cz/2009/01/tomcat-context-listener-example.html)):

```
package com.example;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    /** The servlet context with which we are associated. */
    private ServletContext context = null;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        log("Context destroyed");
        this.context = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        this.context = event.getServletContext();
        log("Context initialized");
    }

    private void log(String message) {
        if (context != null) {
            context.log("MyServletContextListener: " + message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("MyServletContextListener: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

And add the following to `web.xml` (or alternatively, use the `WebListener` annotation or `addListener()` method):

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can include a "ContextListener" in web.xml. An instance of this class would be created when Webb application WAR is about to be deployed/started.

This code can start a thread that would keep running till app is deployed.

Example : http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-233.html

Comment: so then, if i need that program to run continuously  then what do i do?

Comment: You can do System.exec to launch a process. That process would keep running even when app is undeployed or container stops.

Comment: Sir, i need to run a servlet that can run continuously in the background after its deployment.. how do i do that? any suggestions?

Comment: Implement Context Listener interface and start a daemon thread in "contextInitialized" method. That will have your code running continuously in background.

Answer (score 0):

i find a way to run some code only at application (*.war) deployment:
it works at least for jersey servlets with java servlet using javax.ws.rs.core.Application .

The application in the file ApplicationConfig.java (see below) contains a method public getClasses which is called at application deployment.
So adding code in getClasses result in having it executed at application deployment. The only caveit i noticed is that strangely this function is called twice, do not know why ,so i added a global variable in the ApplicationConfig class to know if my code has already run.

Here is my solution:

```
package eu.oca;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**                                                                                                                             
 *                                                                                                                              
 * @author mattei                                                                                                               
 */
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("jersey")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    private boolean alreadyRun = false;

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        System.out.println("Sidonie : ApplicationConfig : getClasses : alreadyRun = " + String.valueOf(alreadyRun));
        alreadyRun = true;
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**                                                                                                                         
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.                                                                           
     * It is automatically populated with                                                                                       
     * all resources defined in the project.                                                                                    
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().                                                            
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(eu.oca.ResultatGeneralAF.class);
        resources.add(eu.oca.ResultatGeneralF.class);
        resources.add(eu.oca.ResultatMesuresAF.class);
        resources.add(eu.oca.ResultatMesuresF.class);
        resources.add(eu.oca.SidonieAccueilD.class);
        resources.add(eu.oca.SidonieWelcomeR.class);
    }

}
```