# Loading my ServletContextListener in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7

New to Tomcat and running Tomcat 7 in an Eclipse environment.

I followed [a tutorial](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.com/2009/01/tomcat-context-listener-example.html) for creating a `ServletContextListener` class. My question is, simply, how do I get this loaded and running in Tomcat? Can I use annotations? Do I need to edit an xml file?

Comment: See also the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5336243/2032064

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to the rescue:

> In order to receive these notification events, the implementation
>   class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web
>   application, annotated with WebListener, or registered via one of the
>   addListener methods defined on ServletContext.

Comment: Ha! In my defense I looked for docs on Tomcat annotations in general. =) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

As an example in the web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>fully qualified class name of your listener class</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I used an annotation, but this is helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

When you download Tomcat 7.0 from the Apache Tomcat website you'll get a version that includes an examples application. There is source code and configuration for some of the Servlet 3.0 features, like annotations.

Have a look at those examples - they're useful.